# What will happen to speed of my sound if I'am moving while producing sound? (animation included)

Tags: reference-frames, acoustics, observers

(The question is very ambiguous, here is the actual scenario I am talking about. I will rename the question, if its required in future.)

If I am standing still and I produce a sound pulse in direction perpendicular to me, and ***then*** I start moving, my sound will move in direction perpendicular to me and reflect back on same path. (Scenario B of animations)

If I am moving with some velocity already, and then I produce a sound ***while moving*** (and I produced this sound perpendicular to me), will the sound pulse gain my horizontal velocity as well? (Scenario C)

i.e will I observe my sound travelling perpendicular to me all the time? (Scenario C)

And will the sound travel in a diagonal path for an external observer? (Scenario C)

**OR**, will my sound pulse not gain my horizontal velocity, and travel in the same way, as shown in Scenario B?

[image]

[image]

I’m  hoping that its possible to produce a sound pulse that doesn't spread out, i.e stays a pulse as I have shown in diagrams, If thats not the case, then please answer the question for a spreading sound, otherwise keep the discussion simple with single pulse.

Another thing, this question is actually precursor to a main question, which I will ask later and link here.

Comment: Sound travels at a constant speed relative to the air, so scenario B is the answer (as long as the air around you is at rest)

Comment: @user341440 Comments are for improving questions. Comments which say “B is the answer” should be posted as answers.

Comment: maybe it helps clarify your thinking if you drew the four archs subsequently, each starting at the point where your figure is placed at the time of emission? Then you would probably start to think about the direction of emission, as a moving object will likely emit sound in a diagonal direction if all the same things take place as in the static case from your first animation.

Comment: Your question has a conceptual problem.

Answer (score 8):

Sound, unlike light, is a disturbance in a physical medium. Once you have made the sound, its propagation is determined by the medium, not by any initial momentum.

Imagine throwing rocks into still water, making circular waves. The waves spread outward with a speed on the order of one meter per second. If the water is flowing (but still has a smooth surface), the upstream speed and the downstream speed of the waves are the same in the water’s rest frame. If the water is moving faster than the speed of the wave, the wave just won’t make it upstream — even if you throw the rock in an upstream direction, or use a boat to make your waves.

Whether you can make a confined “sound wavepacket,” like you’ve drawn, is a separate question. Spherical waves are a better model for sound. Considering spherical waves gives you the Doppler effect.

Comment: Thanks. My actual question was regarding light. If we consider that light travels in 'ether medium', and in my question, I produced a light pulse(instead of sound), then will the answer remain the same?(by ether I mean, according to the ether theory of light).

Comment: @RohitShekhawat Yes, but ether theory is false (it was soundly disproven about 130 years ago and has since been absolutely buried under a mountain of empirical disconfirmation), so that answer would be false.

Comment: @gs so they say, but all M&M did was to disprove their assumptions.

Comment: @WeatherVane His contributions to small chocolate candies and Dre's legacy of first-rate hip hop artists are unmistakable, but the more salient experiments are the trillions of hours of experimental disconfirmation done by the people who watched cathode ray tube television sets and computer screens and found that they did, in fact, work.

Comment: @RohitShekhawat Beware that light waves, sounds waves, and water waves all obey slightly different versions of the wave equation. They have different symmetries under translations and boosts, and different dispersion properties. Reasoning by analogy must be done with care.

Comment: Light in ether medium is a very good hypothesis. So good that most scientists used to think it was true. But then they discovered it wasn't. Unfortunately reality trumps nice hypotheses.

Answer (score 5):

> So the audio gains his velocity.

No, absolutely not. What changes is the frequency of the sound (the [Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect)).

Remember: sound isn't an object that travels. Nothing is going anywhere. Sound is a local disturbance of the air.

Sound is a wave effect that *propagates* through the medium of air, water etc.

Comment: Thanks. If we consider that light travels in 'ether medium', and in my question, I produced a light pulse(instead of sound), then will the answer remain the same?(by ether I mean according to the ether theory of light)

Comment: The ether theory of light has long since been discredited, precisely for this reason (experiments show that light pulses do not behave like sound pulses).

Comment: @Rohit the question does not mention light.

Comment: @EricSmith I saw a video on michelson-morley experiment that showed that when light hits the beam splitter and goes upward, it travels in same fashion as Scenario C ( based on ether theory). Am I mistaken somewhere? Should I ask a seperate question regarding this.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for confusion. I aked a seperate new question my comment, in which i replaced the sound pulse by light pulse, and 'air medium' by 'ether medium'.

Comment: @EricSmith but Michelson & Morley's experiment was a straw man. They made assumptions about what "should" happen, and when it didn't, reckoned they disproved the ether theory, not their assumptions. Had they done it post-Einstein, no-one would have expected the speed of light to differ. I sometimes wonder if dark matter is the new ether.

Comment: @WeatherVane: there have been plenty of other experiments since Michelson & Morley, all with the same null result -- there is absolutely no experimental evidence for an ether.

Comment: @EricSmith but the jury is still out, no? Nobody can really explain light, dark matter, the universe, everything. What we have is improved models.

Comment: @WeatherVane : no, the jury is not still out. Light is thoroughly understood in the context of quantum electrodynamics. There are some things physicists don't understand, but light is not one of them.

Comment: @EricSmith its behaviour models may be well understood, but not its nature. Please don't confuse scientific description with reality.

Comment: @WeatherVane: please don't confuse your own lack of understanding with that of physicists. Pop science accounts do not capture the reality of physics very well at all.

Comment: @EricSmith I don't look at pop science. I am trying to say physics is about modelling reality. We don't, and we never will, know the exact nature of reality. Some physicists do know there is a difference between the scientific models, and reality. My comment about M & M experiment is not trying to say the ether exists: the only thing they really disproved was their expectations, but that model has gone out of favour. Welcome dark matter. Tell me you fully understand it.