# Why does light (supposedly) move diagonally in Michelson-Morley Experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, aether

(Im specifically referring to [this video at 12:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQGGSNIWm3o&t=733s))

In Michelson-Morley experiment, one light beam goes perpendicular to the velocity of earth, and other goes parallel to the velocity of earth.

Im really confused about the treatment we give to the perpendicular beam.

Here's what I have understood so far. The ether is at rest. Earth is moving towards right at 30kmps. There is a fixed speed of light in ether(just like sound).

The guy in the video is saying that the light travels in diagonal path since our setup has moved ahead.

Here are the questions:

1. From who's perspective (experimenter or person outside earth frame) is the light travelling in that path?
2. If its travelling like that in 3rd person's perspective, then shouldn't the light travel completely vertical in experimenter's persective? (why are we considering 3rd person's perspective anyways, if the parallel beam's time of travel was calculated in earth's frame)
3. When light hits the splitter, then how could it go in diagonal direction anyways? Shouldnt it hit the splitter and move in completely vertical direction in the ether, and meanwhile the setup moves ahead and the light beam hits a bit behind the splitter after it has returned from the mirror.
   Similar to [this video at 2:57](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6gd3bQLiFc&t=201s)
4. Take a look at this [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762727/) question I asked earlier, which was asked just for 'this' current question. If you replace sound with light, and air with ether, we get same situation as in michelson experiment(dont we?). Then how could sound not travel diagonally in that question, but light can travel diagonally in this question. Where is this dissimilarity coming from?

Comment: Is this a history-of-science question about what the ether hypothesis predicted, or a physics question about what really happens?

Comment: Even in the earlier question, you seem to have a serious confusion as to what light waves actually do. You cannot make the beam not have a slight slanted component. Any source of light tends to want to spread out in a spherical form. And then the geometry of the system setup and its motion makes the part that contributes to the interference be the diagonal path.

Comment: It is necessary to consider the wave aspect of the light at the departure and arrival, compares the reflection coefficient of the two phenomena: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations and formula (1.29) here: http://web.mit.edu/1.138j/www/material/chap-3.pdf  , same formulas ''to the nearest exponent''.

Comment: @gs Im really sorry i forgot to mention it. It is indeed 'history-of-science question about what the ether hypothesis predicted'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From whose perspective (experimenter or person outside earth frame) is the light travelling in that path?

There is no person’s perspective indicated. The indicated path is in the frame where the aether is at rest.

> If its travelling like that in 3rd person's perspective, then shouldn't the light travel completely vertical in experimenter's persective?

There is no 3rd person’s perspective. We are using the aether frame because we know that light follows Maxwell’s equations in this frame.

> When light hits the splitter, then how could it go in diagonal direction anyways? Shouldnt it hit the splitter and move in completely vertical direction in the ether

No. It is unclear why you think this is the case. The fact that light is observed to reach the detector clearly indicates that whatever logic leads you to believe otherwise is wrong.

You should clarify your own thinking, and if you still are stuck then open a new question with sufficient detail. But you need to recognize that the observation of light at the detector clearly indicates that the light strikes the mirrors as indicated.

> Then how could sound not travel diagonally in that question, but light can travel diagonally in this question. Where is this dissimilarity coming from?

It is not a dissimilarity. Sound would travel diagonally too. You appear to have the same misunderstanding about sound as you do about light.

Comment: (part 1) Thanks a looooot for such an elaborate answer.  You said "The indicated path is in the frame where the aether is at rest." Iam assuming that ether is actually at rest, like it is the earth moving and ether is the only thing at complete rest in the universe. So, when light strikes the splitter, then from earths' perspective it goes up and comes down, COMPLETELY Vertically. But ether's perspective says it follows diagonal path. So, the light DOES follow the diagonal path. Meaning that after hitting the splitter it DOES move in a diagonal direction in ether medium. (part 2 below)

Comment: So, a sensation(wave) must be produced by the splitter that made the light travel in the diagonal direction. Thats what is confusng me. What caused the light to head in that diagonal direction? Did the splitter produce the a diagonal moving wave? Shouldnt the spitter produce a perpendicular wave in even in ether's frame? (Are my 'assumptions and ideas' still incorrect)

Comment: @RohitShekhawat yes, in the aether frame it does move diagonally. Yes, the splitter reflected the wave in that direction. No, the splitter shouldn’t have reflected the wave perpendicularly. The light follows Maxwell’s equations in the mirror’s frame. You can use Huygen’s principle to find the angle of reflection from a moving mirror, but since the light is observed to make it to the detector the final result is clear

Comment: oh my god, thats what i wanted to know. I dont understand how huygens principle would make light go in diagonal direction , but my confusion is clear now. Thanks a loooot again :)

Comment: Could you tell me how huygens principle causes light to move diagonal?(if feasible)

Comment: @RohitShekhawat that is too involved for comments, but here is a paper that goes into a lot of depth https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.04471

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot Dale, I really dont have anyone to discuss physics with, and it gets really hard to ask the questions precisely in written form, and abiguity creeps in. Thanks for helping me out :D

Comment: @RohitShekhawat no worries. If you want discussion you might consider a real forum, like physicsforums.com. This site is intended for questions and answers, not for discussion

Answer (score 2):

We know from countless experiments that light and sound have different characteristics, so you cannot always safely reach conclusions about one by analogy with the other. That said, let's leave all that aside and consider the following set-up...

Imagine you are able to direct a sound vertically upwards to reflector from which it bounces straight back down to you. In your frame the sound has just moved straight up and down. Now view it from my frame, where I am walking past you. In my frame the sound follows a diagonal path. Exactly the same reasoning applies to light. If in your frame you flash a light directly upwards at a horizontal mirror, the light will bounce back to you- the path of the light is straight up and down in your frame. If I am moving past you horizontally, in my frame the light follows a zig-zag path.